# Strange errors after new React Native project rendered in Browser

Tags: react-native, expo

I am pretty new to React Native and encounter some strange errors after creating a new project.

In the terminal I have created a new React Native project with the following steps:

```
npx create-expo-app awesomeproject
cd awesomeproject
npx expo start
```

When I Hit `w` to open the project in the Browser (Chrome), I get a blank page with a lot of errors in the console (see below).
When I open the same project in the Expo App, it works fine and I see 'Open up App.js to start working on your app'.

I feel like those errors are related to an older React Native project (cache?). I already closed the browser, Visual Studio code and the terminal but get those errors over and over again. Do you guys have any idea what's going wrong and how to solve this?

````
react.development.js:209 Warning: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.
printWarning @ react.development.js:209
error @ react.development.js:183
resolveDispatcher @ react.development.js:1592
useState @ react.development.js:1621
DevLoadingView @ DevLoadingView.tsx:9
renderWithHooks @ react-dom.development.js:16305
mountIndeterminateComponent @ react-dom.development.js:20074
beginWork @ react-dom.development.js:21587
beginWork$1 @ react-dom.development.js:27426
performUnitOfWork @ react-dom.development.js:26557
workLoopSync @ react-dom.development.js:26466
renderRootSync @ react-dom.development.js:26434
performConcurrentWorkOnRoot @ react-dom.development.js:25738
workLoop @ scheduler.development.js:266
flushWork @ scheduler.development.js:239
performWorkUntilDeadline @ scheduler.development.js:533
react.development.js:209 Warning: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.
printWarning @ react.development.js:209
error @ react.development.js:183
resolveDispatcher @ react.development.js:1592
useState @ react.development.js:1621
DevLoadingView @ DevLoadingView.tsx:9
renderWithHooks @ react-dom.development.js:16305
mountIndeterminateComponent @ react-dom.development.js:20074
beginWork @ react-dom.development.js:21587
callCallback @ react-dom.development.js:4164
invokeGuardedCallbackDev @ react-dom.development.js:4213
invokeGuardedCallback @ react-dom.development.js:4277
beginWork$1 @ react-dom.development.js:27451
performUnitOfWork @ react-dom.development.js:26557
workLoopSync @ react-dom.development.js:26466
renderRootSync @ react-dom.development.js:26434
performConcurrentWorkOnRoot @ react-dom.development.js:25738
workLoop @ scheduler.development.js:266
flushWork @ scheduler.development.js:239
performWorkUntilDeadline @ scheduler.development.js:533
react.development.js:1622 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useState')
    at useState (react.development.js:1622:1)
    at DevLoadingView (DevLoadingView.tsx:9:1)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:16305:1)
    at mountIndeterminateComponent (react-dom.development.js:20074:1)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:21587:1)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:4164:1)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:4213:1)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4277:1)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:27451:1)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:26557:1)
useState @ react.development.js:1622
DevLoadingView @ DevLoadingView.tsx:9
renderWithHooks @ react-dom.development.js:16305
mountIndeterminateComponent @ react-dom.development.js:20074
beginWork @ react-dom.development.js:21587
callCallback @ react-dom.development.js:4164
invokeGuardedCallbackDev @ react-dom.development.js:4213
invokeGuardedCallback @ react-dom.development.js:4277
beginWork$1 @ react-dom.development.js:27451
performUnitOfWork @ react-dom.development.js:26557
workLoopSync @ react-dom.development.js:26466
renderRootSync @ react-dom.development.js:26434
performConcurrentWorkOnRoot @ react-dom.development.js:25738
workLoop @ scheduler.development.js:266
flushWork @ scheduler.development.js:239
performWorkUntilDeadline @ scheduler.development.js:533
react.development.js:209 Warning: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.
printWarning @ react.development.js:209
error @ react.development.js:183
resolveDispatcher @ react.development.js:1592
useState @ react.development.js:1621
DevLoadingView @ DevLoadingView.tsx:9
renderWithHooks @ react-dom.development.js:16305
mountIndeterminateComponent @ react-dom.development.js:20074
beginWork @ react-dom.development.js:21587
beginWork$1 @ react-dom.development.js:27426
performUnitOfWork @ react-dom.development.js:26557
workLoopSync @ react-dom.development.js:26466
renderRootSync @ react-dom.development.js:26434
recoverFromConcurrentError @ react-dom.development.js:25850
performConcurrentWorkOnRoot @ react-dom.development.js:25750
workLoop @ scheduler.development.js:266
flushWork @ scheduler.development.js:239
performWorkUntilDeadline @ scheduler.development.js:533
react.development.js:209 Warning: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.
printWarning @ react.development.js:209
error @ react.development.js:183
resolveDispatcher @ react.development.js:1592
useState @ react.development.js:1621
DevLoadingView @ DevLoadingView.tsx:9
renderWithHooks @ react-dom.development.js:16305
mountIndeterminateComponent @ react-dom.development.js:20074
beginWork @ react-dom.development.js:21587
callCallback @ react-dom.development.js:4164
invokeGuardedCallbackDev @ react-dom.development.js:4213
invokeGuardedCallback @ react-dom.development.js:4277
beginWork$1 @ react-dom.development.js:27451
performUnitOfWork @ react-dom.development.js:26557
workLoopSync @ react-dom.development.js:26466
renderRootSync @ react-dom.development.js:26434
recoverFromConcurrentError @ react-dom.development.js:25850
performConcurrentWorkOnRoot @ react-dom.development.js:25750
workLoop @ scheduler.development.js:266
flushWork @ scheduler.development.js:239
performWorkUntilDeadline @ scheduler.development.js:533
react.development.js:1622 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useState')
    at useState (react.development.js:1622:1)
    at DevLoadingView (DevLoadingView.tsx:9:1)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:16305:1)
    at mountIndeterminateComponent (react-dom.development.js:20074:1)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:21587:1)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:4164:1)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:4213:1)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4277:1)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:27451:1)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:26557:1)
useState @ react.development.js:1622
DevLoadingView @ DevLoadingView.tsx:9
renderWithHooks @ react-dom.development.js:16305
mountIndeterminateComponent @ react-dom.development.js:20074
beginWork @ react-dom.development.js:21587
callCallback @ react-dom.development.js:4164
invokeGuardedCallbackDev @ react-dom.development.js:4213
invokeGuardedCallback @ react-dom.development.js:4277
beginWork$1 @ react-dom.development.js:27451
performUnitOfWork @ react-dom.development.js:26557
workLoopSync @ react-dom.development.js:26466
renderRootSync @ react-dom.development.js:26434
recoverFromConcurrentError @ react-dom.development.js:25850
performConcurrentWorkOnRoot @ react-dom.development.js:25750
workLoop @ scheduler.development.js:266
flushWork @ scheduler.development.js:239
performWorkUntilDeadline @ scheduler.development.js:533
react-dom.development.js:18687 The above error occurred in the <DevLoadingView> component:

    at DevLoadingView (http://localhost:19006/static/js/bundle.js:1433:66)
    at withDevTools(App)

Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.
Visit https://reactjs.org/link/error-boundaries to learn more about error boundaries.
logCapturedError @ react-dom.development.js:18687
update.callback @ react-dom.development.js:18720
callCallback @ react-dom.development.js:13923
commitUpdateQueue @ react-dom.development.js:13944
commitLayoutEffectOnFiber @ react-dom.development.js:23391
commitLayoutMountEffects_complete @ react-dom.development.js:24688
commitLayoutEffects_begin @ react-dom.development.js:24674
commitLayoutEffects @ react-dom.development.js:24612
commitRootImpl @ react-dom.development.js:26823
commitRoot @ react-dom.development.js:26682
finishConcurrentRender @ react-dom.development.js:25892
performConcurrentWorkOnRoot @ react-dom.development.js:25809
workLoop @ scheduler.development.js:266
flushWork @ scheduler.development.js:239
performWorkUntilDeadline @ scheduler.development.js:533
react.development.js:1622 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useState')
    at useState (react.development.js:1622:1)
    at DevLoadingView (DevLoadingView.tsx:9:1)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:16305:1)
    at mountIndeterminateComponent (react-dom.development.js:20074:1)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:21587:1)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:27426:1)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:26557:1)
    at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js:26466:1)
    at renderRootSync (react-dom.development.js:26434:1)
    at recoverFromConcurrentError (react-dom.development.js:25850:1)```

I closed the Browser, terminal and Visual Studio code and tried to set up a new React Native project again.
````